# How to execute commands inside docker container from Jenkins

Tags: linux, shell, docker, jenkins, docker-compose

My requirement is to manually add certificate to the keystroe in Java which is in container. For this , I am using below commands.

`sudo docker exec -it my-container-name bash` --> to go inside container

`cd /java/lib/security` -- > chnage directory to java security path

`keytool -keystore cacerts -storepass changeit -noprompt -trustcacerts -importcert -alias testcert -file /cert/test-Base64.cer` --> install certificate

The above commands are working fine. Now, I would like to automate this from Jenkins. I mean, i want these commands to be executed after
'`sudo docker-compose up -d`' .

Can anyone please help.

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't add the certificate already in the build phase? just adding a RUN with your 3 commands is easier. If the certificate is dynamic it may work out better to script this so that it executes when the container is running at the moment you need the certificate

Comment: Thank you @sleepyhead , I just did it in the way you suggested , using RUN in the docker file and execute two commands which i needed. it worked for me .

Answer (score 0):

If you still wanted to do it after the container starts, use

```
sudo docker exec -it my-container-name bash -c "cd /java/lib/security; keytool -keystore cacerts -storepass changeit -noprompt -trustcacerts -importcert -alias testcert -file /cert/test-Base64.cer"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should generally find ways to avoid `docker exec`, especially for scripted use like this.  (It’s very conceivable that automated tasks will delete and recreate containers and won’t have your manual setup steps.  This is doubly true in clustered environments like Docker Swarm or Kubernetes.)

In the case where you have some existing keystore file that you just want to inject into the container, the easiest way is to push it in at startup time using the `docker run -v` option.  You’d need a fully populated keystore file already.

```
docker run \
  -v $PWD/keystore.jks:/usr/lib/java/jre/lib/security/keystore.jks \
  ...
```

If you can’t inject a fully populated keystore file at startup time, you can write a script that runs at container startup time.  It looks for some well-known directory, runs the `keytool` command on every file there, and then runs the command it was passed as command-line arguments.

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ -d /cert ]; then
  for f in /cert/*.cer; do
    keytool ... -file "$f"
  done
fi
exec "$@"
```

In your Dockerfile, COPY this script in and make it the ENTRYPOINT.  If you previously had an `ENTRYPOINT ["java", ...]` line, change that to a CMD.  This will look something like

```
FROM java:8
...
COPY entrypoint.sh /app
ENTRYPOINT ["/app/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["java", "-jar", "/app/myapp.jar"]
```

Then when you run the container, inject the `/cert` directory

```
docker run \
  -v $PWD/cert:/cert \
  ...
```